# Dark theme does not work with React Stitches

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, stitches

I'm using [Stitches](https://stitches.dev/docs/theming) in React to handle my CSS and theming. I have the following code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { createStitches, globalCss } from '@stitches/react'

const { theme, createTheme } = createStitches({
  theme: {
    colors: {
      text: 'blue',
      bodyBg: 'lightgray',
    },
  },
})

const darkTheme = createTheme('dark-theme', {
  colors: {
    bodyBg: 'black',
  },
})

const globalStyles = globalCss({
  'body': {
    color: '$text',
    backgroundColor: '$bodyBg'
  },
});

function App() {
  globalStyles()
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

As you can see, I have a default theme, and then a dark theme that extends the default theme while overriding some properties (in this case, the `bodyBg`). I'm applying these styles directly in my `<body>`. The default theme works fine, but the dark theme does not. When I add the `.dark-theme` class to my `<html>`, nothing changes (the background should turn black). What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stitches-dark-mode-te4ne?file=/src/ColourModeProvider.tsx) it might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably trying to add the class directly to the body in the developer tools which doesn't work.

I managed to make it work with a button onClick event:

```
const darkTheme = createTheme('dark-theme', {
  colors: {
    bodyBg: 'black',
  },
})

function App() {

  const setBlackTheme = () => {
    document.body.classList.remove(...document.body.classList);

    // Here we set the darkTheme as a class to the body tag
    document.body.classList.add(darkTheme);
  }

  globalStyles()
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <button onClick={setBlackTheme}>Dark Theme</button>
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Try it and let's see if it works for you as well.

Comment: Hmm still doesn't seem to work. The class gets added, but the new theme doesn't get applied.